# Codeigniter not getting data though available in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a model which fetch the data from database is below

```
public function counselor() {
    $inst_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $submission_key=$this->session->userdata('submission_key');
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM counselor where USER_ID = $inst_id AND submission_key= $submission_key");
    $data = $query->num_rows();
    if ($data > 0) {
        return $data;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have tested the `$inst_id` and `$submission_key` by printing it and its set.
`$inst_id=2` and `$submission_key=2016-8` .BUT though I have one record in database with those two field set its not returning the data. What is the case. I have tried with codeigniter `get()` and `where()` method too. Still not giving me the result.

Comment: `$submission_key=2016-8` should be `$submission_key='2016-8'`

Comment: SELECT * FROM counselor where USER_ID = $inst_id AND submission_key= $submission_key" am passing the variable

Comment: i changed -(minus) ti underscore and now throwing this error Unknown column '2016_8' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM submission where USER_ID = 2 AND submission_key=2016_8

Answer (score 1):

Just write your query using active record function. It will help you in escaping string

```
 $this->db->select('*',FALSE);
    $this->db->where('USER_ID',$inst_id);
    $this->db->where('submission_key',$submission_key);
    $query=$this->db->get('counselor');
    $data = $query->num_rows();
    if ($data > 0) {
        return $data;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: **Unknown column '2016_8' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM submission where USER_ID = 2 AND submission_key=2016_8**
am getting this error even with this

Comment: the column name exist

Comment: What is the datatype of column `submission_key`??

Comment: Try with use FALSE at last in select!! check updated code

Comment: not fixed yet, Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'submission_key' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM (`counselor`) WHERE `USER_ID` = '2' AND `submission_key` = '20168'

Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\scholarship\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Comment: `submission_key` column not exist in your database. Check is there any space before column name in your phpmyadmin